# Programatically creating buttons on an applications FIRST Run and Save it for future runs

Tags: vb.net, list, button, view, addition

I am developing an application (VB.NET and Visual Studio 2010 Pro) and require assistance on the following:

1) Items / products are stored in a database, these items are stored under specific groups.

2) Upon the loading of my form, I need to get a list of all the groups in the items table and create a button for each group item, in addition to this it will have to add a tab for each group to the adjacent Tab Control. I've been able to do this however not using buttons, rather I'm using a list view. My perfect solution would be able to do this using buttons.

3) After creating the buttons for the tabs and their respective tabs I need to further populate each tab with the items that are listed under the respective groups, here too the items need to be displayed as buttons in the ideal situation but I will use a list view if I have to.

4) I would like to make it that once the buttons for the groups and items are created it must be saved as part of the interface if not permanently just for the session for which the application is running. (i.e t must not have to be re created every time the tab page is loaded it should just be created once for each time the application is run.)

here is the code I have for getting the groups from the DB and populating the list view along with the code for generating the tabs and adding a list view to the tab:

```
 Private Sub frmItemSearch_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstItemGroups.Clear()
    tbItemGroups.TabPages.Clear()
    If openConnection(SQLConnection6) Then

        Dim cmd2 As String = "select distinct itemgroup " & vbCrLf & _
                             "from stkitem" & vbCrLf & _
                             "where ItemGroup != ''" & vbCrLf & _
                             "order by ItemGroup asc"

        SQLCommand5 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmd2, SQLConnection6)
        SQLReader6 = SQLCommand5.ExecuteReader

        While SQLReader6.Read
            lstItemGroups.Items.Add(SQLReader6.Item(0))
        End While

    End If
    Dim x, i, index As Integer
    x = lstItemGroups.Items.Count
    i = 0
    index = 0
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage()

    'MessageBox.Show(x)

    While i < x
        NewTab.Text = lstItemGroups.Items(i).Text
        tbItemGroups.TabPages.Insert(index, NewTab)
        i += 1
        index += 1
    End While

End Sub



 Private Sub lstItemGroups_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstItemGroups.Click

    Dim lstMenuItems As New ListView()
    lstMenuItems.BackColor = Color.Blue
    lstMenuItems.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    lstMenuItems.Items.Add("A")
    lstMenuItems.Items.Add("A")
    lstMenuItems.Items.Add("A")
    lstMenuItems.Items.Add("A")
    lstMenuItems.Items.Add("A")

    Dim index As Integer = lstItemGroups.SelectedIndices(0)
    tbItemGroups.SelectedIndex = index

    tbItemGroups.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(lstMenuItems)

End Sub
```

The problem here is that when I click on the group, the respective tab is selected but the list view is not added to the tab. If I can get this to happen, populating it with the items from that group would be achievable as it will be the same as populating the groups in the groups list view. (The items added to the list view in my code are just for test purposes.)

SO In summary,

The main issue is how do I add the list view to the dynamically generated tab?

If you can assist with a solution to using buttons instead of a list view that would be awesome and I would greatly appreciate that.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Perhaps you should change the title to reflect the exact problem here: "Problems while adding controls to TabControl" or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `Tabs` wrongly what provokes the whole `TabControl` to be faulty and, consequently, no `Controls` can be added to it. The right way to do this is:

```
While i < x
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage() 'This has to be called as many times as tabs to include
    NewTab.Text = lstItemGroups.Items(i).Text
    tbItemGroups.TabPages.Insert(index, NewTab)
    i += 1
    index += 1
End While
```

After this correction, the code in the `lstItemGroups_Click` will work fine. Nonetheless, bear in mind that you are adding the controls without specifying size (`Width`/`Height`) and location (`Left`/`Top`) within the given tab; you should account for those issues.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I have also accounted for the location. I did not specify a height and width as I am setting its dock style to fill the tab.

Comment: @KavirM You are welcome. It sounds good anyway: you have just to make sure that that all the controls to be added are perfectly defined (dimensions and location) in order to avoid the default values to come into picture; the exact method you use to do this is not important.